# uploading custom windows server 2012R2 image on Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to upload Windows Server 2012 R2 image on Google cloud to save license cost from Google, as i already have spare licenses to use.

please let me know the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking about a possibility of bringing your existing Windows Server licenses to Google Compute Engine (BYOL).
Windows Server licensing terms are quite complicated and can sometimes vary from customer to customer, so it is recommended to contact
Microsoft licensing specialists that can give you the most qualified answer about BYOL tailored to your unique circumstances.

Having said this, under Microsoft Volume Licensing, you are generally not eligible to run Windows Server in a shared compute environment
such as GCE or any other public cloud. Instead, Google like other providers licenses Windows Server from Microsoft using SPLA program that
has its own unique terms.

On the other hand, Microsoft applications, such as SQL Server, Exchange, Sharepoint, and others can be brought to GCE (or other public clouds)
relatively easily using Microsoft license mobility program. You can read about license mobility program here: 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows#microsoft_license_mobility

--Alex