# Google Cloud and Bizspark licenses

Tags: windows-server-2012, google-cloud-platform, windows-server

My team has Bizspark account and we want to use free licenses for Windows Server 2012.

Is it possible to set Windows Server 2012 license key manually somewhere in Google Cloud Service? And if we'll change it in OS, will Google anyway take our money?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my question:

> you are generally not eligible to run Windows Server in a shared compute environment such as GCE or any other public cloud

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30720911/1850880